# TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Date'

Tags: pandas, quantlib

I am new to python. I am getting an error when running below code. The issue seems to be with date. can someone help me to correct i please. I have tried changing the date format in the excel but it does not solve the issue. The excel have a list of several bonds. I want to generate the coupon dates of the different bonds

```
BondData = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Avishen\Desktop\Python\BONDDATA.xlsx')
Data = pd.DataFrame(BondData)

def scheduledates():
    tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
    day_count = ql.Thirty360
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
    businessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
    dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
    monthEnd = False

    # Dates in Bond Period
    return ql.Schedule (issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, businessConvention,
                            businessConvention , dateGeneration, monthEnd)

new_df["Dates"]= Data.apply(lambda x: scheduledates(),axis = 1)
new_df["ISIN"] = Data.ISIN
new_df


Error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-877415e9cf83> in <module>
     21                             businessConvention , dateGeneration, monthEnd)
     22 
---> 23 new_df["Dates"]= Data.apply(lambda x: scheduledates(),axis = 1)
     24 new_df["ISIN"] = Data.ISIN
     25 new_df

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7546             kwds=kwds,
   7547         )
-> 7548         return op.get_result()
   7549 
   7550     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    178             return self.apply_raw()
    179 
--> 180         return self.apply_standard()
    181 
    182     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    269 
    270     def apply_standard(self):
--> 271         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    272 
    273         # wrap results

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    298                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    299                     # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 300                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    301                     if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    302                         # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-4-877415e9cf83> in <lambda>(x)
     21                             businessConvention , dateGeneration, monthEnd)
     22 
---> 23 new_df["Dates"]= Data.apply(lambda x: scheduledates(),axis = 1)
     24 new_df["ISIN"] = Data.ISIN
     25 new_df

<ipython-input-4-877415e9cf83> in scheduledates()
      8 
      9 def scheduledates():
---> 10     issueDate = ql.Date(Data.issuedate)
     11     maturityDate = ql.Date(Data.maturitydate)
     12     tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py in __init__(self, *args)
    425 
    426     def __init__(self, *args):
--> 427         _QuantLib.Date_swiginit(self, _QuantLib.new_Date(*args))
    428 
    429     def weekdayNumber(self):

TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Date'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Date::Date()
    Date::Date(Day,Month,Year)
    Date::Date(Day,Month,Year,Hour,Minute,Second,Millisecond,Microsecond)
    Date::Date(Day,Month,Year,Hour,Minute,Second,Millisecond)
    Date::Date(Day,Month,Year,Hour,Minute,Second)
    Date::Date(BigInteger)
    Date::Date(std::string const &,std::string)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------


Data = pd.DataFrame(BondData)
Fields from Bond Data
    ISIN
    issuedate
    maturitydate    
coupon  
Tradeyield
    Bond_Price
    MarketPrice
    Nominal_Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback, the problem is the line:

```
issueDate = ql.Date(Data.issuedate)
```

(which for some reason is not in the code you pasted).  Coming from Excel, `issuedate` should be an integer and thus compatible with the `ql.Date` constructor, but it's possible that pandas is reading it as a string or some other type.  You should examine the data frame and check the type of the column.  If it's not what you expect, you'll have to figure out if there are data in that column that pandas can't interpret as integers, and either clean them up of force the conversion somehow before passing them to `ql.Date`.

Comment: Thanks @Luigi Ballabio.  Mange to solve it